# move django application to a live database

Tags: django, migration, live

We have a Django web based application comprised of many apps that is currently using a test database (a copy of the live database with the Django auth and other bits added into it) and now we would like to move/migrate/point to a live database version. The documentation I have found so far does not tell me how to do this. So the question is, How do I point this application to the live database (with no Django tables currently) and get the required Django tables and such added in so the app functions correctly when pointed at the live database?  The app is built with Django 1.5 and Python 2.7.

Comment: Why would that be different from when you set up the test database? Just change the DATABASES setting and run syncdb.

Comment: Will that create missing tables (in the new database) that django had created in the old database? And populated them?

Answer (score 0):

Just point to the new database, and run a

```
python manage.py syncdb
```

It'll automatically create all the tables for you.